# tkinter button to run command and destroy popup window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working in Python 3 with tkinter and would like to have a button in a popup window both run a command and destroy the popup window. The code I have below works on the frontend, but gives an error on the command line, is this an issue that is resolveable?

The error that I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:Python34\lib\tkinter__intit__.py", line 1538 in __call__
>   return self.func(*args)
>   File "test.py", line 14, in 
>   command = lambda: display_something() * popup.destroy())
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
from tkinter import *

class MainView(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        new_popup = Button(self,text = 'Make A Popup!',
            command = lambda: popup()).grid(row=0,column=0)


def popup():
    popup = Toplevel()
    button = Button(popup, text = 'Display something on the command line',
        command = lambda: display_something() & popup.destroy())
    button.pack()

def display_something():
    print('popup ran the command')

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Eric\'s Archiver')
    app = MainView(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can you add the error message to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is "and" operator but for `bits`, not for `booleans`.

You need boolean operator `and`.

But in your code `or` should work better because first function returns `None` which is treated as `False` - and `False and anything` gives always `False` so there is no need to execute `anything`. But `False or anything` may gives `False` or `True` depending on `anything` so it has to execute `anything` to get final result.).

```
lambda: display_something() or popup.destroy()
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for the explanation as well!